# SecurityContextHolder.getContext() is same in different browser tabs

Tags: java, spring-security

I have a problem in my web application.

Siatuation as-is and step by step:

1. open first session in a browser
2. debug and see

   `SecurityContextHolder.getContext() = A`
3. open second session (in different tab of the browser)
4. debug and see

   `SecurityContextHolder.getContext() = B`
5. come back to debug first session and see

   `SecurityContextHolder.getContext() = B`

So first session's context was rewritten.

Have you any idea to fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you know the contextA is different from the contextB? Different object references? They hold different Authentication instances? What strategy is used to store the context?

Comment: excatly so. different principal names for example.

Comment: are you logged in as the same user in both sessions?

Comment: Do you open the sessions in defferent browsers or the same browser but in different tabs/windows?

Comment: different tabs in chrome. and I logged in with different usernames.

Comment: if you start the sessions with different users, then it looks like there is nothing wrong with such behavior. the A session was invalidated and you have the B session in both tabs. But it may be the issue with your security setup. I would expect you should be kicked off in the A tab.

Comment: when I use chrome for session A and safari for session B I have no the problem.

Comment: then there is no problem :)

Comment: so is normal situation when I have "mixed" sessions in different tabs of one browser?

Comment: the thing is that you do not have two sessions in different tabs. When you start the B session, the A becomes invalid. After you have refreshed the A tab, you are in the B session again.

Comment: @Vasyl thanks a lot. the trouble is you have not separate solution here to give you a point. so just thank you again.

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at the Spring Security FAQ section on [Session Management](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-session-management), particularly 2.1, which talks about the relation between browser windows, tabs and sessions.